# In ASP.net nested Page is not showing labels

Tags: asp.net

I have a master page named `MainMasterPage.master` i have a `contentplaceholder1` and `contentplaceholder2`. Further, i am creating a nested master page which is using the `contentplaceholder1`, in this i am placing the labels. But these labels are not showing up.Where am i going wrong ?

In Nested master page

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cntplace1" Runat="Server">
    <table width="100%">
    <tr> <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblImmu" Text="Immunization Details"></asp:Label></tr>
    <tr><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDel"></asp:Label></tr>
    <tr><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMal"></asp:Label></tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can't really tell without code to look at. There are a number of things, most likely of which is no `Text` value for the labels. Add some code here so we can help you more.

Comment: In Master Page:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="cntplace1"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
In NestedMasterPage <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cntplace1" Runat="Server">
    <table width="100%">
    <tr> <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblImmu" Text="Immunization Details"></asp:Label></tr>
    <tr><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDel"></asp:Label></tr>
    <tr><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMal"></asp:Label></tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>

Comment: missing TDs just add td after the tr.

Comment: I did it, it showed on the design but when i run it it wont show it.